# While Deploying Python Flask App to Azure App Service getting error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'

Tags: python, azure, flask, azure-web-app-service

While Deploying Python Flask App to Azure App Service getting error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy'

Code is running fine locally.

I am following the azure guidelines .
Steps Followed:-

```
1. Created virtual environment
2. added all packaeges using pip freeze command to requirement file
3. created azure app service in portal
4. Adding following configurations     SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT=true    PYTHON_DEFAULT_VERSION=3.9   
WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_RETENTION_DAYS=3
5. az login
6. az webapp up -n <appservicename> (to deploy the app)
```

No Start up command is used as my file name is app.py and its in root folder.

I have tried with Visual studio Extn also same result and error.

Can someone help , i am sure i am missing something small and stupid.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is spacy in the requirements.txt file in your folder as well?

Comment: @anthonyshaw i yes spacy as well as en_core_web_lg is in requirments file

Answer (score 0):

Could you confirm how have you deployed your virtual environment? Its suggested to
not deploy your virtual environment with your application code as Virtual environments are not portable.

Instead you can create an app setting, `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT`, and setting it to `1` this will let Oryx create a virtual environment and install your packages on the web app and will force Oryx to install your packages whenever you deploy to App Service.

Suggest you to refer this [article on virtual environment portability](https://azure.github.io/AppService/2020/12/11/cicd-for-python-apps.html#flask-and-vuejs).

Comment: Hi Sneha, actually i didn't deploy the virtual environment i used SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT= true in configurations of Azure App service . In requirement file pip freeze command as well , it has spacy as well